# How do I have an arrow follow different height parabolas depending on how long the player holds down a key?

Tags: xna, c#, algorithm, trajectory

i'm trying to throw an arrow in my game, but i'm having a hard time trying to realize how to make a good parabola.

What I need:
The more you hold "enter" stronger the arrow goes.
The arrow angle will be always the same, **45 degrees**.

This is what I have already have:

```
    private float velocityHeld = 1f;
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
 private void GetKeyboardEvent()
        {
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter) && !released)
            {
                timeHeld += velocityHeld;
                holding = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (holding)
                {
                    released = true;
                    holding = false;
                    lastTimeHeld = timeHeld;
                }
            }
        }

        if (released && timeHeld > 0)
        {
        float alpha = MathHelper.ToRadians(45f);
        double vy = timeHeld * Math.Sin(alpha);
        double vx = timeHeld * Math.Cos(alpha);

        ShadowPosition.Y -= (int)vy;
        ShadowPosition.X += (int)vx;
        timeHeld -= velocityHeld;
        }
        else
        {
            released = false;

        }
       }
```

My question is, what do I need to do to make the arrow to go bottom as it loses velocity (timeHeld) to make a perfect parabola?

Answer (score 3):

You're already calculating the launch velocity; after launch, the X velocity of the object remains constant over time, and the Y velocity has constant downward gravitational acceleration applied to it over time.  Then you simply apply the velocity as usual in a physics engine.

For more information, if you search for "parabolic trajectory", "ballistic trajectory" or "projectile trajectory" you'll find all kinds of articles and demos on the subject.  For example, see [Projectile motion on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

The standard treatment ignores air resistance, but you can incorporate that as well if you like; it only requires adding a drag force proportional to the negative of the object's current velocity.  You can find this discussed many times on the Web as well.